# Why doesn't this work for the last 4 or 5 indexes of the string?

Tags: python, indexing

The purpose of this code is to make the odd placed letters uppercase and the odd ones lowercase.

```
def myfunc(word):
    new_word = ''
    for let in word:
        if (word.index(let) + 1) % 2 == 0:
            new_word += let.upper()
        elif (word.index(let) + 1) % 2 == 1:
            new_word += let.lower()
            
    return new_word
```

It works fine for the first few but when it gets towards the end it loses its brain cells.

Input:
`myfunc('Anthropomorphism')`

Output:
`'aNtHrOpOmOrpHIsm'`

Expected Output:
`'aNtHrOpOmOrPhIsM'`

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`word.index(let)` will get you the *first* index of that letter, not the current one as you iterate. Use `for index, letter in enumerate(word):` instead.

```
def myfunc(word):
    new_word = ''
    for index, let in enumerate(word):
        if (index + 1) % 2 == 0:
            new_word += let.upper()
        elif (index + 1) % 2 == 1:
            new_word += let.lower()
            
    return new_word
```

or slightly more concise:

```
def myfunc(word):
    new_word = ''
    for index, let in enumerate(word):
        new_word += let.upper() if index % 2 else let.lower()
    return new_word
```

and even a pythonic 1-liner:

```
def myfunc(word):
    return ''.join(let.upper() if index % 2 else let.lower() for index, let in enumerate(word))
```

Comment: What exactly does enumerate do?

Comment: Spot on.  One minor suggestion - can do `enumerate(word, 1)`  Later it can save +1 math.

Comment: you don't even need that `+1`: `(index + 1) % 2 == 0` is the same as `index % 2 == 1` and  `(index + 1) % 2 == 1` is the same as `index % 2 == 0` and 1 evaluates as Truthy so you can make it more concise as in edit.